# Reference a Control on Content page from master Page

Tags: asp.net

How do I get a reference to a label on the content page from the master page? I need to access the control that is on the content page from the load event of the Master page.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's the use case?

Comment: I have a security object in the master page load event. I refresh it for certain pages. I want to reflect a result in the content page via  label. I prefer to put this feed back in the content page not the master page simply because it looks nicer since my matser page is basically a header on every page

Comment: Seems like in improper use of master/content pages. If you've got a control that needs to be accessed by the master page, it should be in the master page. ContentPlaceHolders should be defined for all of the sections of the that are controlled by the content page.